# Why can a standalone component be provided in a unit test?

Tags: angular

In [Angular's test examples](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/testing/stackblitz.html), they include the following, in `welcome.component.spec.ts`:

```
describe('WelcomeComponent (class only)', () => {
  let comp: WelcomeComponent;
  let userService: UserService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      // provide the component-under-test and dependent service
      providers: [WelcomeComponent, { provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService }],
    });
```

They are treating a standalone component like an `Injectable`, providing it along with another dependency. The `WelcomeComponent` retrievable from `TestBed.inject` then uses the `MockUserService` instead of the default `UserService`. (Providing a mock service to a standalone component using `useClass` is otherwise only possible via `TestBed.overrideComponents`.)

Why can a standalone component be treated as an `@Injectable`?

Comment: Not just in tests - that's the point of [standalone components](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components), they can be injected like any other provided item, without needing a module.

Comment: I don't think that the referenced documentation mentions this behavior. My impression is that the point of standalone components is that they become unique compilation units in and of themselves, and basically can replace NgModule. I don't understand how they can be otherwise treated as injectables in their own right. They obviously can be... but I don't know the full scope of what has changed.

In other words, if they replace an NgModule, I would expect them to be imported, not provided.

Comment: You could also place it in the `imports` array and initialise it using the following:

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;